# Сравнение всех полей двух классов

Tags: java, android

У меня в классе куча полей и каждый раз писать такого рода проверки кажется мне не правильным, вот:

```
if (tmpProfileModel != null) {
                    if (tmpProfileModel.getLastName().equals(profileModel.getLastName()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getFirstName().equals(profileModel.getFirstName()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getBirthday().equals(profileModel.getBirthday()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getGender().equals(profileModel.getGender()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getFacebook().equals(profileModel.getFacebook()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getInstagram().equals(profileModel.getInstagram()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getEducation().equals(profileModel.getEducation()) &&
                            tmpProfileModel.getImage().equals(profileModel.getImage())) {
                        intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.IS_EDITED_KEY, false);
                    } else {
                        intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.IS_EDITED_KEY, true);
                        intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.EDITED_OBJECT_KEY, profileModel);
                    }
                }
```

Еще дюжина полей, которое урезал.
Теперь мне нужно проверить все эти поля на `Null`, будут еще много проверок и уже путаюсь.

Как вы решаете такого рода задачи?

Comment: Можно загнать проверяемые значения в списки, напр. `Arrays.asList( some.foo(), some.bar(), some.baz() ).equals( Arrays.asList( other.foo(), other.bar(), other.baz() ) )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме выноса логики сравнения в отдельный метод (о чем написал @Serodv) можно использовать [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), который сравнивает два значения принимая во внимание `null`:

```
boolean isPartiallyEqual(Model other) {
    if(other==null) return false;
    return Objects.equals(getFirstName(), other.getFirstName()) &&
           Objects.equals(getBirthday(), other.getBirthday()) &&
           ...
}
```

Для большего упрощения можно подключить [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) и использовать [`EqualsBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html).

С помощью этого класса можно проверить все поля с помощью рефлексии:

```
return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other);
```

либо построить свой объект сравнения с заданным списком полей:

```
if(other==null) return false;
return new EqualsBuilder()
             .append(getFirstName(), other.getFirstName())
             .append(getBirthday(), other.getBirthday())
             ...
             .isEquals();
```

Comment: Какой бы вы использовали, Objects или Apache?

Comment: @DevOma Для простого сравнения `Objects`, т.к. для простой задачи хочется обойтись стандартными классами. Но Apache Commons поддерживает сценарий с динамическим набором полей (рефлексией).

Comment: Еще вопрос в Apache Common можно ли проверить не поля а обьекты типа такого EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(newInstance, oldInstance)? То есть не прописывая все поля?

Comment: @DevOma Ну так для этого `reflectionEquals` и нужен. Метод динамически сравнивает все имеющиеся поля. Имейте ввиду, что рефлексия медленнее обычного доступа к полю. Также если имеются поля унаследованные от класса-родителя, то может потребоваться их включить/исключить. В общем, почитайте документацию к методам `reflectionEquals` (их несколько с разными аргументами) и тщательно протестируйте код.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло! А вот `Objects.equals` работает оказывается начиная с API19

Comment: @DevOma Пожалуйста, рад что получилось! Андроидом я сейчас не занимаюсь и как-то, признаться, упустил этот момент.

Answer (score 2):

Реализуйте в своём классе методы, обеспечивающие проверки

```
class SomeClass {
...
    boolean someEquals(SomeClass someObj) {
        return getFirstName().equals(someObj.getFirstName()) &&
               getBirthday().equals(someObj.getBirthday()) &&
               getGender().equals(someObj.getGender()) &&
               .....;
    }
}
```

ну и проверка

```
if (tmpProfileModel.someEquals(profileModel))
```

Comment: Я думал о таком, но хотелось бы еще короче..)

Comment: Могу предложить сгруппировать методы в какие-то группы, и затем пользоваться комбинациями сравнения. Но опять же, изменение структуры класса либо логики приведёт к неизбежному хаосу